# Placement of sidebar and section next to each other - sidebar pushing my sections down a line.

Tags: css, html

I floated my sidebar to the right. I'm having trouble trying to get the  of class container to hang out to the left of the side bar. I tried floating the side bar to the left, but it seem like my containers get pushed down. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/6k3mp/1/

```
#sidebar {
margin: 10px 0 0 0; 
border: 2px solid black;
float:right;
width:150px;
height:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remember you need to rest the border from the width

In your case Width 150px Border 2px ----> Width = 150-2px(from left)-2px(from right) = 146px

Do the same with your container....

Answer (score 0):

An easy answer us to add this to your CSS:

```
section{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are specifying the width of the article.container elements as 100%. Since there is not enough room for it to have the width that you ask it, the browser pushes it down. If you put a margin-right of 15em on the containing  element, the containers will be placed correctly as seen in this fork of your jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PSk36/1/

The principal change was adding a class to the  (simply for targetting from CSS) and then adding the following rule:

```
section.the-section {
  margin-right:15em;
}
```

You typically must allocate room for floated sidebars using margins or padding.